# Docker base image with the Solaris operating system

Tags: docker, solaris, docker-machine, docker-registry, dockerhub

Does anybody know from where I can get docker base image with Solaris OS in it?

I tried finding it on Dockerhub but couldn't find one.

Please provide me the detail 'dockerhost/namespace/imagename:tag'

Comment: Since docker images share a kernel with the host, and Solaris uses a different kernel to Linux, a docker Solaris image would only work on a Solaris host. Furthermore I don't think docker is working yet on Solaris - though there's some plan to get this working, see: https://forums.docker.com/t/installing-docker-on-solaris-11u2-or-u3/9129

Comment: Thanks @Matthew.

my intention is to have a docker container with Solaris base running on CentOS or RHEL. Seems not possible as of now.

Comment: Or indeed ever :), docker only works for OSes sharing a kernel. What you are looking for is a virtual machine. Checkout [vagrant](http://www.vagrantbox.es/), or similar.

Comment: Dang, too bad it has to share the kernel. I'd really like this as well.

Comment: @Matthew I believe vagrant is more a tool to offer abstraction over provisioning machines on ec2, digitalocean, google cloud etc. For VM on solaris, the option should be VirtualBox. (VB and solaris are both owned by solaris)

Comment: @AnthonyKong afair Vagrant is just a recipe of how the VM image should look like and this can then be run on various things like ec2 and others, but the default is to fire up a VirtualBox VM with the recipe.

Comment: @Matthew can't you use docker on windows to run linux containers too? why shouldn't the same work with Solaris?

Comment: @ColbyBlair No, it's wonderful that it shares a kernel ;-) That means docker containers start up FAST and run just as fast as a "native" (out-of-container) application. It seems like a bad thing when you want to run a different kernel, but that's only because you're trying to misuse containers. What you're looking for is a virtual machine (which virtualizes the kernel among other things). Look at QEMU, virtualbox, etc.

Answer (score 10):

Short answer: **NO**

Long answer:

Since docker images share a kernel with the host, and Solaris uses a different kernel to Linux, a docker Solaris image would only work on a Solaris host.

Furthermore docker is not yet working on Solaris. More information on that on stackoverflow: [Is it possible to install docker on Sparc machines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52947908/is-it-possible-to-install-docker-on-sparc-machines)

Answer (score 3):

No. Docker it is a "new technology". Virtualization on operation system level  (you can say it is chroot) it is old conception.
But UNIX have that technology and better technology.

In Solaris it is zones(containers) if you know dtrace you can write a scripts for zones. I think very intresting Solaris ldom and Solaris VM.

In FreeBSD it is jail(ezjail).

In Aix it is LPAR and other I dont know.

In HP-UX Npar and Vpar, Integrity Virtual Machines.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle possibly has vagrant images for Solaris as it uses virtual box by default instead of hiper-v. However current docker version can be configured for virtual box also, but vagrant is better if you consider it from Solaris perspective. The Solaris is not available in docker because Oracle did not provide an image for Solaris.

If you want to stick with docker only then I will stick with the other's responses.