# Run linux-docker-image on a Solaris machine, how?

Tags: docker, solaris

How do I run on solaris, a linux based docker-image (e.g nginx image)? I expect similar to running a nginx-image on windows machines.

e.g Can I have a virtualbox-linux in solaris-os, and then run docker run nginx? What are the ways?

Comment: Similar: [Is it possible to install docker on Sparc machines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52947908/is-it-possible-to-install-docker-on-sparc-machines)

Answer (score 1):

[There is currently no support for Docker on Solaris.](https://forums.docker.com/t/installing-docker-on-solaris-11u2-or-u3/9129)

[Docker containers rely on their hosts kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32756988/what-is-meant-by-shared-kernel-in-docker), that's why Docker only works on linux systems or if the operating system provides a linux kernel. (WSL makes Docker work on Windows)

Comment: Traditionally you've "run Docker" on non-Linux hosts by running a Linux virtual machine, and tools like Docker Machine for that are still around.  This will only get you so far if you're on Sparc hardware and can't run x86 or ARM images.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your question but maybe the `--platform` might help you

You can use it in the `docker run` command if your host is multi-platform capable https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

```
--platform      Set platform if server is multi-platform capable
```

e.g.

```
docker run -d nginx --platform arm64 ...
```

Hope this helps!